# Q. The two points $(a,2)$ and $(-3,b)$ lie on 1st and 3rd quadrant respectively.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

Q. The two points $(a,2)$ and $(-3,b)$ lie on 1st and 3rd quadrant respectively. If $ab \neq 0$, in which quadrant does the point $(a,b)$ lie?

a). 1st quadrant

b). 2nd quadrant

c). 3rd quadrant

d). 4th quadrant.

I couldn't get any idea to interpret the question. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: $(a,2)$ in $QI$ should tell you something about the sign of $a$.  Same applies to $(-3,b)$.  Put those together.  Do you know what is meant by quadrants?

Comment: @Sharding4, Then $(a,b)$ lies on 4th quadrant, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.

Comment: @AlbertEinstein  I suggest you answer your own question, then accept it so that the question can be closed.